# angularjs not refreshing client after action

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a like/unlike functionality on images. the like/unlike is toggled using ng-class.  On clicking the icon, it makes a service call and toggle the state. However, this is not reflecting on ui.

my **html** is:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" ng-repeat="result in searchCtrl.searchResults">
        <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="http://site.jpg">
            <div class="overlay">
                    <a ng-click="searchCtrl.likeImage(result)">
                    <span ng-class="'{{searchCtrl.getImageClass(result)}}'"></span></a>
    </div>
```

my js looks like

**JS**

```
app.controller('SearchController', function(){
    this.getImageClass = function(result){
            if(result.liked)
                return 'fa fa-heart fa-4x';
            else
                return 'fa fa-heart-o fa-4x';   
        };

        this.likeImage = function(result){
             if(result.liked == false){
                 myService({'mediaId':result.mediaId}).execute(function(resp) {
                     if(resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                      }else{
                         result.liked = true;
                      }
                     });
             }
        };
```

Comment: Is it not reflecting on UI or page is reloading? I assume post title is misleading.

Comment: thanks fixed the title

Comment: can you confirm that your ng-class is in fact being called and returning the expected class

Comment: do u mean after the respone? i am not explictly calling it and was hoping angular somehow refreshes it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your problem is that your service ('myService') sends some http request. And angularJS does not start dirty checking after http response recieved. You should do it in your callback.

```
this.likeImage = function(result){
       if(result.liked == false){
           myService({'mediaId':result.mediaId}).execute(function(resp) {
               if(resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                }
                else{
                   result.liked = true;                       
                }
                //pay attention there
                $scope.$apply();
               });
       }
  };
```

There is an example:  https://jsfiddle.net/aL5sqs31/2/.
I've tried to create some dummy myService. It sets timeout instead of http request, but conception is the same

Comment: What exactly your service do? Http request? Did you check it really calls your callback? Did you check full js-fiddle example in attached link?

Comment: By the way, also replace `<span ng-class="'{{searchCtrl.getImageClass(result)}}'"></span>` with `<span ng-class="searchCtrl.getImageClass(result)"></span>` like it's in jsfiddle example

Comment: thanks i was missing the html part. now wondering if there is a rule on when to put in {{'  ?

Comment: you shouldn't use {{}} inside ng-class. Ng-class is a directive, which evaluates passed expression. If you want to use expression in a form of {{}}, you could write this `<span class="{{searchCtrl.getImageClass(result)}}"></span>` (just class, not ng-class)